# Capture client browser console using Shell and save it to a file

Tags: scripting, shell, console, javascript

I want to find a way to capture a client browser console that is using my server, and save it to a file inside the server, is this possible using a shell script ?

Comment: You want to log the Console of a Browser that is remote? Or are you talking about Terminal=Console as in ssh? (but I see Browser) Your question needs clarification..or more focus..

Comment: No, i'm talking about the client when using a browser, i want to capture the console that appears when pressing "F12", save it to a file in the server and not in the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prohibit the local Browser from visualizing its Console contents.

You could use [console.save](http://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/#console-save) to save the contents locally.

If you want to somehow send those contents to Your box, you could do this possibly with additional AJAX call.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but, i'm looking for a shell/server side solution if possible.

Comment: I would say it is impossible for you to grab Client side output, solely from the Server side. It just does not make sense in any viable way.

Comment: That's what i thought too, thank you for your answer.